# Pandas group by multiple custom aggregate function on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate

Given data:

| grp | data1 | data2 | data3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| a | 4 | 6 | 3 |
| b | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| b | 7 | 3 | 5 |

Expected output:

| grp | sum(data1) | sum(data2)/sum(data1) | sum(data3)/sum(data1) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 6 | 1.166666667 | 0.83 |
| a | 10 | 0.5 | 0.6 |

Assume custom aggregation can be dependent on multiple columns and not always a simple division operation. I know using SQL query it's possible, but I am interested in an answer with apply and aggregate function if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
df2 = df.groupby('grp').sum()
df2.update(df2.drop(columns='data1').div(df2['data1'], axis=0))
```

or more classically:

```
df2 = df.groupby('grp').sum()
df2[['data2', 'data3']] = df2[['data2', 'data3']].div(df2['data1'], axis=0)
```

output:

```
     data1     data2     data3
grp                           
a        6  1.166667  0.833333
b       10  0.500000  0.600000
```

###### multiple aggregation

You can use the same logic with a MultiIndex:

```
df2 = df.groupby('grp').agg(['sum', 'mean'])
df2.update(df2.drop(columns='data1').stack(0).div(df2['data1'], axis=0).unstack())
```

output:

```
    data1      data2      data3     
      sum mean   sum mean   sum mean
grp                                 
a       6  3.0     7  3.5     5  2.5
b      10  5.0     5  2.5     6  3.0
```

Comment: what if I want other aggregation also like average? here you used the sum for all columns, but that is not usually what I have to do. 
Eg: sum(data1), avg(data2), min(data2), sum(data2)/sum(data1) etc

Comment: please check the above comment. @mozway

Comment: @Parshantgarg did it work for you?

Answer (score 2):

You can use groupby + assign here to generate required aggregations. You can apply whatever aggregate function is needed.

```
g = df.groupby('grp')
#                                         for custom agg func use .agg(custom_agg_func)
#                                                          ^^^^^
g[['data1']].agg('sum').assign(sum2 = lambda df: g['data2'].sum()/df['data1'],
                               sum3 = lambda df: g['data3'].sum()/df['data1'])
#                ^^^^^^
#    you can use custom agg func of your choice

     data1      sum2      sum3
grp                           
a        6  1.166667  0.833333
b       10  0.500000  0.600000
```